# Bootstrap4-toggle switch button displaying like checkbox

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

I want make `switch button` but that is displaying like `checkbox`. Following [this article bootstrap4-toggle](https://gitbrent.github.io/bootstrap4-toggle/) .

My buttons should look like this

[image]

But looking like this

[image]

I have added reference links

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

I have install library too

```
npm install bootstrap4-toggle
```

This is my code

```
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="lg">
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="sm">
<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="xs">
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

bootstrap4-toggle requires jQuery. Add a jQuery CDN along with the reference links. For example, add the following CDN inside your head tags.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```